# No named parameter with the name 'dataRowMaxHeight'. - firebase_ui_firestore - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

Hi I am facing this issue when I am trying to build my flutter app in Xcode. The whole error message is the below

*../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_firestore-1.5.1/lib/src/table_builder.dart:301:23: Error: No named parameter with the name 'dataRowMaxHeight'.*

I tried to upgrade the package but did not work. I have cleaned my project, have repaired the pub cache but nothing seems to solve this issue. Any help is welcomed, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `pubspec.yaml`,try to replace

> `firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.5.1`

with

> `firebase_ui_firestore: 1.4.0`

dont put the ^ symbol for that version and try to run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. If u want to run for iOS device, try to run through xcode first after doing this.

Thats what i did after a few days figuring that out. Hope that helps

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Any idea what might be causing this bug?

Comment: @lgbokwenu its related to flutter version if im not mistaken but im not sure.. but there are some packages that need to be written as above example... for my case, this package and helpers package also need to be in a certain version without the ^ sign..

Comment: thanks Anas, I followed a similar approach, I had to go lower on the version of the package in my case, and finally it worked

Comment: Also, I updated the framework in the latest stable version. maybe this helps others

Comment: @Igbokwenu the main cause is probably your flutter version is lower than current up to date version.